# Curl always timeout, Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Tags: php, curl

I am not sure, is it from deadlock or no.
But before I got this issue, I was use curl to same server.

I was looking for this issue, 
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=deadlock+curl

But it does not solve the problem.

```
<pre>

<?php
  session_write_close(); 
  // session_start([
  //   'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
  //   'read_and_close'  => true,
  // ]);
  echo 'ada';
  print_r($_SESSION);
  print_r($_SERVER);
  echo'wow';
  // die();
  $curl = curl_init();
  $data = "waidiidwada";

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://hooks.slack.com/services/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"text\":\"$data\"}",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "Accept: */*",
      "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
      "Cache-Control: no-cache",
      "Connection: keep-alive",
      "Content-Length: 24",
      "Content-Type: application/json",
    ),
  ));


  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);

  curl_close($curl);

  if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
  } else {
    echo $response;
  }

  session_start();

?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score -2):

Solved.

i delete this line

```
"Accept: */*",
      "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
      "Cache-Control: no-cache",
      "Connection: keep-alive",
      "Content-Length: 24",
```

Comment: What does that mean? What **exactly** did you change to solve **which** problem?

Comment: Most likely it had to do with "Content-Length" not being equal the actual length of data submitted in the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.